# Copying Image Using Python Pyperclip

Tags: python, image, pyperclip

I referred to an older post that used 'win32clipboard' to accomplish this task. However, when I tried installing it with `pip install win32clipboard` I encountered the following error:

```
'ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32clipboard (from versions: none). ERROR: No matching distribution found for win32clipboard.
```

I'm asking this because I think `win32clipboard` is not available to me.

```
from PIL import Image
import pyperclip

# Open the image file
image_path = 'img.png'
image = Image.open(image_path)

# Copy to the clipboard
pyperclip.copy(image)
```

I am encountering an error while using the Pyperclip library in my Python script. When attempting to copy a file to the clipboard, I receive the following exception:
`pyperclip.PyperclipException: only str, int, float, and bool values can be copied to the clipboard, not PngImageFile`

I understand that Pyperclip only supports copying string, integer, float, and boolean values to the clipboard. However, in my case, I need to copy a `.png` file on clipboard.

Comment: `win32clipboard` is only available on Windows.  Which operating system are you using?  The clipboard on Linux is a vast unregulated junkheap.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 but it isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by installing win32clipboard!
**pip install pywin32**